Computational complexity of “Linear divisibility” problem (Adleman & Manders 1972)
[Information/resource request]
Linear Divisibility:
In the study of $\gamma$-reduction that generalizes Karp reduction, Adleman and Manders [1972] mentioned the following language:
$$A = \{\langle a,c\rangle \mid a,c\in\omega\text{ and }(\exists x\in \omega) [x\neq0\text{ and }ax+1\text{ divides }c]\}.$$
It is conjectured to be outside $\mathrm{NP\cap coNP}$ in  [AM72] (page 2, Theorem I). It was open question if it is NP-complete (under Karp reduction).
What is current known status of this problem?
